# VBA code works in step-through, skips a file when run

Tags: excel, vba, step-into

The code below works great when I do a "Step into" the code, and pastes the data from each file into the "Cisco Database" file. However, when I just run it, it always leaves off the last file. I added a specific line to save the DB file each time, to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
Sub AppendDataFinal()

Dim myWorkbook As String
myDB = "CiscoDatabase.xlsx"
myWorkbook = "Cisco.xlsm"

Application.Run "'Cisco.xlsm'!importfile" //grabs all .csv files from a folder

For Each wb In Workbooks
If (wb.Name <> myWorkbook) Then wb.Activate

Columns("A:O").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("O:AS").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Open ("file path")
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste , False
Range("A1").Select
If (ActiveWorkbook.Name = myDB) Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Next wb


Workbooks.Open ("file path and name")

Application.Run "Cisco.xlsm!DateFormat" //trims time off date row, pretties up data


End Sub
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify a collection such as `WorkBooks` while you're looping though it. You should maybe create an array or collection of the names of the files you want to operate on, and then loop through that instead.

Comment: What file is this code running in? If it's Cisco.xlsm then you don't need to use `Application.Run` to call another macro in the same file.

Comment: Thank you so much, I truly appreciate your looking at this hotmess. No matter how many tutorials I read I can't seem to find really clear explanations on working on these.

Comment: Are you initially trying to append CSV files? you can do it like this in a DOS prompt: COPY File1.CSV + File2.CSV + File3.CSV Output.CSV. This assumes file names are consistent etc. But it's more reliable than custom VBA code

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using a collection (untested)

```
Sub AppendDataFinal()

Const MY_DB_PATH As String = "C:\pathToYourDBHere\"
Const MY_DB As String = "CiscoDatabase.xlsx"

Dim colNames As New Collection, wbName
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbDB As Workbook
Dim myDB As String

    importfile  'grabs all .csv files from a folder

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        'ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook containing this code
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then colNames.Add wb.Name
    Next wb

    'open the destination workbook
    Set wbDB = Workbooks.Open(MY_DB_PATH & MY_DB)

    For Each wbName In colNames

        Set wb = Workbooks(wbName)
        With wb.Sheets(1)
            .Columns("A:O").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            .Columns("O:AS").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
                  wbDB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With
        wb.Close False
        wbDB.Save

    Next wbName

    wbDB.Activate
    DateFormat 'trims time off date row, pretties up data

End Sub
```